# Here on askubuntu.com is there a way to communicate with another editor or answerer

Tags: discussion, support

On askubuntu.com is there a way to communicate with another editor or answerer without cluttering up the questions and answers with info unrelated to the specific post? As an example I posted an answer which was edited placing some of the output that the OP used in the question which I copied into the answer for clarity. the editor converted this into a code block. I thought perhaps I had made a policy error of some kind, and so used the comment section of the question to query. I'd rather avoid cluttering up Q & A with unrelated comments, hence my question.

Thank you !

Comment: A comment relating to the content of the post *is* a related comment, that's what comments are for ;)

Comment: Thank you for your rapid response!

Comment: Once an issue is cleared you can always delete your comment later if you were worried of clutter.

Comment: Did that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can drop them a line in the [AskUbuntu General Chat Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) and if they aren't present and they've been in recently, they get a message in their inbox.

Comment: Worth noting that you can only ping someone in chat if they have been in the room recently (in the last 2 days I think). If you can tab-complete their username after typing @, you can ping them, otherwise you cannot. You can ask a mod to ping them for you, but that might be more disruptive than a few temporary comments on the post...

Comment: @Zanna thank you for the info. I've edited my answer accordingly.